# Pandas column header

Tags: python, excel, pandas, header

i have multiple excel files that contains similar information that i want to bring in as list into python with pandas. Every file contains a table that has the info that i want but this table in some files starts at row 5 or in other in row 10 or 23 and go on (because before this table there are some titles that change from one file to others) so this cannot be a constant BUT the headers of the table are the same, can i tell pandas "take all data under the row with "specific name"" ? or have i to tell every time the right index?

Thanks! Have a good work!

Edit:
To make it more clear this is how pandas read my dataframe (based on excel file)

[image: DataFrame Example]

So as you can see in row 2 (in this example) there is the raw with "Draw, Back#,Horse,Rider...) and this is my "keyrow" so i want that my df starts under this row so i can use all below datas to make my folders but as i said this row is the same with all excels but in every excels is in different row.

Comment: So every file starts with empty rows and do you want to skip those rows or do you just want to read every file after a specific row whether it is empty or not?

Comment: No, starts with some rows of introduction text to the table where i want data but this introduction is different everytime

Comment: Yes, you have to tell the right index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the multiple Excel files have the same column headers, you could create a filter to "take all data under the row with "specific name"".

This can be done using `df['col_name']=='specific name'` which will return an array of `True`/`False` values.

```
filter = df['col_name']=='specific name'
```

After that, apply the filter (array of `True`/`False` values) to the dataframe, which will keep those values that are `True` only

```
df.loc[filter]
```

For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_name': ['nothing', 'specific name', 'specific name', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah'], 
              'col_2': ['blah blah', 'blah', 'blah blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah'] })

        col_name      col_2
0        nothing  blah blah
1  specific name       blah
2  specific name  blah blah
3           blah       blah
4           blah       blah
5           blah       blah

filter = df['col_name']=='specific name'
print(df.loc[filter])

        col_name      col_2
1  specific name       blah
2  specific name  blah blah
```

Comment: thanks @Tyler2P, I've improved my answer, please let me know if my answer is useful :-)

Comment: Thanks @threadfin ! When i'll go home i will try it and let you know! :)

Comment: It doesn't work like that.

Comment: hi @Vitalizzare, would you give more details to "doesn't work like that" please?

Comment: First, you are processing data after reading. So, it's not an answer on the OP. Second, say you have several cells with `specific name`, so you get several cells with `df.loc[filter]`. Also, what exactly are you looking for with this code? Why didn't you go further and get the index to split by, like `df.loc[df.loc[filter].index[...which one?...]:]`

Comment: so.. i will explain it shortly.. i need to make unique folders in sport event competion to put pictures in of the rider (equestrian sport)...so the show office can give me an excel with the start list and inside in the first rows there are some logos and infos of the event (because they print it also) and than the table with the startlist where i need to get info to make them in folder so i will have a folder for every member of startlist. So i also made a script for this but i'm making a little software with gui so every member of my team can use it.

Comment: so the process will be to read the excel path, than from that excel the script automatically knows that has to read data below some keywords (the table header) and than output the folders to a 'x' directory

Comment: hi @MatteoPetrillo I think I've worked my answer based on my (wrong) understanding, so would you add these details and some examples in the question?

Comment: @threadfin i edited the question with example and explaining it better! :) thanks for help anyway!

Comment: i solved with `for row in range(df.shape[0]): 

        for col in range(df.shape[1]):

            if df.iat[row,col] == 'Draw':

                row_start = row
                break
        
    newdf = df.loc[row_start:] `

Thanks anyway and have a good work!

Comment: Bravo! thanks to all who contributed their ideas/feedback

Answer (score 0):

With the index, you can use the below code.
If you have excel values with row 4 header and from row 5 the rest data

col_name = excel_df.iloc[3:4,:].values.tolist()

df = excel_df.iloc[ 4:,: ]

df.columns = sum(col_name, [])

df